# get the value from a pointer to a float32 from inside a struct?

Tags: go

I am pulling in some data from a db - and I have a pointer to a float32 - because if I use a pointer - then I am able to check if it is nil (which it quite often might be).

When it is not nil, I want to get the value - how do I dereference it so I can get the actual float32? I can't actually find a link for that anywhere! I know exactly what I want to do, and I just can't find the syntax in Go, which I am still very new to - all help appreciated.

I know how to dereference the pointer if it is a straight float32...

but if I have the following struct...

```
type MyAwesomeType struct{
    Value *float32
}
```

Then after I do :

```
if myAwesomeType.Value == nil{
    // Handle the error later, I don't care about this yet...
} else{
    /* What do I do here? Normally if it were a straight float32
     * pointer, you might just do &ptr or whatever, but I am so
     * confused about how to get this out of my struct...
    */
}
```

Answer (score 4):

> [The Go Programming Language Specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec)
>
> [Address operators](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Address_operators)
>
> For an operand x of pointer type *T, the pointer indirection *x
>   denotes the variable of type T pointed to by x. If x is nil, an
>   attempt to evaluate *x will cause a run-time panic.

---

Use the `*` operator. For example,

```
package main

import "fmt"

type MyAwesomeType struct {
    Value *float32
}

func main() {
    pi := float32(3.14159)
    myAwesomeType := MyAwesomeType{Value: &pi}

    if myAwesomeType.Value == nil {
        // Handle the error
    } else {
        value := *myAwesomeType.Value
        fmt.Println(value)
    }
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/8URumKoVl_t

Output:

```
3.14159
```

---

Since you are new to Go, take [A Tour of Go](https://tour.golang.org/). The tour explains many things, including pointers.

> Pointers
>
> Go has pointers. A pointer holds the memory address of a value.
>
> The type `*T` is a pointer to a `T` value. Its zero value is `nil`.
>
> ```
> var p *int
> ```
>
> The `&` operator generates a pointer to its operand.
>
> ```
> i := 42
> p = &i
> ```
>
> The `*` operator denotes the pointer's underlying value.
>
> ```
> fmt.Println(*p) // read i through the pointer p
> *p = 21         // set i through the pointer p
> ```
>
> This is known as "dereferencing" or "indirecting".
>
> Unlike C, Go has no pointer arithmetic.